# filename and pathname of a file

Tags: files, filenames

It is said that the filename of a file is a pointer pointing to the inode of the file.
Before knowing that, I thought it was the pathname of a file that does that job.

I am not sure how a pathname and a filename are defined in Unix.
For example,  is it correct that
`/home/tim/tim.pdf` is the pathname of the file with file name `tim.pdf`.

I wonder what the difference between the filename and the pathname of  a file? Thanks.

Comment: What is the "pathname of the file"?

Comment: updated. @JosephR.

Comment: "It is said that the filename of a file is a pointer pointing to the inode of the file" - Where is this stated please?

Comment: ["A filename is used to refer to an i-node."](http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs219/CourseNotes/Unix/unix-fileStructure.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [POSIX terminology](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html), a [filename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_170) is the name of a directory entry. It consists of a non-empty sequence of bytes other than `/` or null. The term “pathname component” is synonymous with “filename”. A [pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267) is a string that can contain any non-null byte and that designates a way to locate a file. A pathname consists of a series of filenames, in which all but the last refer to a directory. [Pathname resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267) is the process of locating a file from a pathname.

For example, `/home/tim/tim.pdf` is a pathname. The last component of that pathname `tim.pdf` is a filename; it is the name of an entry in the directory whose pathname is `/home/tim`. The filename `tim` is itself the name of an entry 
in the directory whose pathname is `/home`; this file happens to be a directory. `tim.pdf` is also a pathname: any filename is a pathname that happens to have a single component and designates the file with that name in the current directory.

`/` is a pathname that refers to the root directory. `.` is a filename that exists in every directory and refers to that directory itself. `.` is a pathname which happens to contain a single component and refers to the current directory.

You can think of a filename as a pointer within a directory to an inode that is a file in that directory. A pathname is a specification of where to find an inode. Each component of a pathname is a filename that points to an inode in the directory reached so far (if the file exists). Pathnames either start at the root directory (if they are [absolute pathnames](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_02), beginning with `/`) or at the current directory (if they are [relative pathnames](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_320), not beginning with `/`).

Note that in many texts, the word “filename” (or “file name”) is used to mean what POSIX calls a pathname.

Comment: So `/home/tim/tim.pdf` is `pathname`, and `tim.pdf` is not `pathname`? I think *filename* is only special case of *pathname*. And why in `4.6 Filenames` section, they use `pathname`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html

Comment: @Gnouc `tim.pdf` is a pathname. Any filename is a pathname.

Comment: So Why did you say my answer is wrong?

Comment: @Gnouc You stated that “they use filename and pathname interchangeable”, which is not at all the case. Any filename is also a pathname, but the converse is not true.

Comment: I also said in section `Filenames` only.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks. (1) What is a "basename" of a file? (2) In a filename "tim.pdf", what is "tim" called for the filename? Is "pdf" called the extension name of the filename?

Comment: @Tim The word “basename” has two meanings. It can mean the part of the pathname without any leading directories, i.e. `tim.pdf`. Or it can mean the part of the base name (in the previous sense) without the extension, i.e. `tim`.

Answer (score 6):

A directory contains a list of filename ⇒ inode mappings. Your directory `/home/tim` includes an entry with filename `tim.pdf`, pointing at (say) inode `1234`.

How do we get at that directory? Well, a directory is really a special kind of file that contains those entries. We can find it the same way we find other files, by looking in its parent: `/home` will have an entry with filename `tim` that points to the inode of the directory. In turn, we can find `/home` by looking in its parent, `/`.

`/` is the root, and it's a little bit more special. The system knows how to get to it directly, because it has no parent.

The *name* of a file is the local name it has in its directory: `tim.pdf`. The *path* of a file describes how you get to it from the root: `/home/tim/tim.pdf`. If you like, you can think of that as a set of instructions: first find `/`, then find `home` inside that, then `tim`, then finally `tim.pdf` that you were looking for.

Resolving any path is in effect a recursive algorithm with this pseudocode:

```
inode find_file(inode where_i_am, string[] remaining_path):
    if remaining_path is empty:
         # Nothing more to look at - we've found the file!
         return where_i_am
    current_item = remaining_path[0]
    rest_of_path = remaining_path[1..]
    for entry in directory_entries(where_i_am):
        if entry.filename == current_item:
            return find_file(entry.inode, rest_of_path)
    return file not found
```

We'd find your file with:

```
find_file(inode_of_root, ["home", "tim", "tim.pdf"])
```

---

There are a few cases where things get slightly more complicated, which the pseudocode doesn't cover. One of those is mounts: when you mount another partition at, say, `/home`, the system remembers that when it goes to `/home` it should shift over to that other partition, and start looking for `tim` in the root of that file system instead. The new file system will have its own set of inodes, so you actually need to know both the inode and the device to access a file's data. A real structure actually includes both.

Symbolic links tell the system to go and look up some other path at this point, and then continue on searching from that new location.

Another case is hard links (your old friend). An ordinary file inode can have arbitrarily many hard links to it. You could make a link with `ln tim.pdf pdf.tim`, which would have the same contents and live at the same point on disk. There would be a separate directory entry `pdf.tim` that pointed at the same inode `1234` as the entry for `tim.pdf`. Our algorithm works just fine for this case: a hard link to a file is exactly the same as the original file, and we don't need to distinguish it at all in any way. The fact that a hard link is just another name for an inode is why you can't make hard links across file systems.

Yet another is the special entries `.` and `..`. These are (often, but filesystem-dependent) real directory entries. They're essentially hard links to the directory itself and to its parent. Our algorithm deals with that too. There's an interesting case that comes up with mounts: because the underlying filesystem doesn't know where it would be mounted, it couldn't have the right `..` entry. To deal with that the system essentially cheats and shows the `..` entry from the directory on the parent device, rather than from the root of the mounted file system.

---

So when you're looking at things from the perspective of inodes like this then:

- **A *file name* is a name a particular inode is called inside a particular directory.**
- **A *path* is some instructions for how to reach an inode from a known point.**

Comment: At least in `Linux`, root's parent is itself.

Answer (score 0):

In General, `pathname` and `filenames` are the same. First, read some rules for `filenames` from POSIX documentation:

> 4.6 Filenames
>
> For a filename to be portable across implementations conforming to
>   IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, it shall consist only of the portable filename
>   character set as defined in Portable Filename Character Set.
>
> The hyphen character shall not be used as the first character of a
>   portable filename. Uppercase and lowercase letters shall retain their
>   unique identities between conforming implementations. In the case of a
>   portable pathname, the slash character may also be used.

You can see, in this section, they use `filename` and `pathname` interchangeable.

There also difference between them in process called `Pathname Resolution`:

> 4.11 Pathname Resolution
>
> Pathname resolution is performed for a process to resolve a pathname
>   to a particular file in a file hierarchy. There may be multiple
>   pathnames that resolve to the same file.
>
> Each filename in the pathname is located in the directory specified by
>   its predecessor (for example, in the pathname fragment a/b, file b is
>   located in directory a). Pathname resolution shall fail if this cannot
>   be accomplished. If the pathname begins with a slash, the predecessor
>   of the first filename in the pathname shall be taken to be the root
>   directory of the process (such pathnames are referred to as "absolute
>   pathnames"). If the pathname does not begin with a slash, the
>   predecessor of the first filename of the pathname shall be taken to be
>   the current working directory of the process (such pathnames are
>   referred to as "relative pathnames").

`pathname` is resolved to file, and filename is located in the directory specified by its predecessor.

**Note**

- [POSIX Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html)
- [Linux path_resolution](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

Comment: These citations are very relevant, but your commentary is completely wrong. *Filename* and *pathname* are not at all interchangeable! POSIX uses them for different concepts.