# List files of certain type under a dir?

Tags: ls

If you want to list just directories (in the present directory) use `ls -d */`

What if you want to list just ordinary files, just executable files, or just soft links, or files of any other type?

Because `ls  -F`      appends `*` to executable files,`@` to symbolic linked files, `/` to directories, I tried
`ls -d **` and 
`ls -d *@`, but they don't work.

Comment: Do you have any particular version of **ls** in mind, perhaps the one from **coreutils** (GNU Linux)? Also this sounds more like a job for **find**.

Comment: GNU coreutils 8.12.197-032bb

Answer (score 4):

You can use the file test operators documented in `man test`. For example, to list symbolic links:

```
for i in *;do if [ -L "$i" ] ;then printf -- "%s\n" "$i";fi;done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find`.

List all files:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f
```

List all symbolic link:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type l
```

List all executable:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -perm +111
```

You can read POSIX [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) documentation for more advance options.

Answer (score 2):

A command like `ls -d *@` lists files whose name ends with `@`. The `@` character is part of the pattern that the file name must match. When `ls -F` displays a character after a file name, that character is not part of the file name, it's an extra indication added by `ls` (that's the point of the `-F` option).

`ls` doesn't have an option to select which types of files to list. If your file names don't contain special characters such as newlines or the suffixes that `ls -F` adds, you can use `ls -F` to list certain types of files and filter its output. For example, to list symbolic links in the current directory, you can use

```
ls -F | grep '@$'
```

A more robust way to list files of a selected type is with the `find` command. Unlike `ls`, `find` is recursive; use the `-prune` action to stop the recursion. Another difference is that `find` doesn't treat files whose name begin with `.` (dot files) specially, whereas `ls` skips them, and shell patterns like `*` also skip them. For example, the following command lists the symbolic links in the current directory:

```
find . -name . -o -type l -print -o -prune
```

Another way to perform filtering is to iterate over all files in a loop and make a test to select the one you want.

```
for x in *; do
  if [ -L "$x" ]; then echo "$x"; fi
done
```

In zsh, you can use [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to restrict files by type. For example, the following zsh command lists symbolic links in the current directory:

```
print -rl *(@)
```

Comment: I don't get it - where do you get *unlike `ls`, `find` is also recursive*? Rather, unlike `find`, `ls` is portably specified to handle either case.

Comment: @Tim - I think you mean `ls */`? That is a quality of the shell expanding that to a globbed argument list before then calling `ls` and handing it same. You can see this in action like `(set -x; ls */)` And to get the `/` at the end of all dirtypes you want `ls -p`.

Comment: Thanks. In the stdout output of `ls -d *`, directory names have no `/` at the end. Then why can `ls -d */` match directories? Is `/` in it interpreted literally or as some special character? Note: I am using bash (I don't know which shell I should use, so I use the popular one).

Comment: @Tim - then `ls -dp`? And yeah, `/` is a  special character unless you `set -f` in your shell to disable pathname expansion. Anyway, what Gilles doesn't mention here is that most versions of `ls` actually offer a fairly standardized API for tagging and filtering filenames by file-type, as is represented in your `$LS_COLORS` environment variable. There's more on that [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143885/52934).

Comment: @mike: As a special character, what does `/` mean?

Comment: @Tim - I'm in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) if you want, or you could do another question, but that's probably enough here. Gilles can get pretty persnickety about comment threads like this, and, honestly, he's well within his rights if he does.

Comment: @Tim Pattern matching is performed by the shell. When a pattern ends in a `/`, the shell only selects directories (including symlinks to directories). Run `echo */` to see for yourself that this is unrelated to `ls`. The character `/` separates [pathname components](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146895/filename-and-pathname-of-a-file/147114#147114), or to put it in English, is a directory separator. The consequences of including a `/` character depend on exactly where it is; at the end of a shell pattern, it means “match directories only”.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest considering `perl`, because it has a useful built in operator - `grep`. Which unlike the command version, actually enables a 'code block' test.

So you can:

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", grep { -d } glob "$dir/*"'
```

Which which will print files matching the `-d`  test and a variety of others:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Answer (score -2):

Say you want to see only c source files (suffix .c) in a list:

```
ls -l *.c
```

This will list all c code files.

Enjoy